# Can I edit java sources on oracle database with Netbeans?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

While exploring my database in Netbeans I could only see Tables, Views and Procedures in schema tree. So these are the only types of objects that it could explore? What about Java sources and java classes at least?

Comment: You're storing Java code in your database? WTF?

Comment: @Matt, Oracle allows writing stored procedures in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best IDE for Oracle is JDeveloper.

Free download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html

Comment: CAN YOU TELL ME HOW TO EDIT JAVA SOURCES VITH JDeveloper? It opens all sources in readonly mode! I can't edit them and there are no options in how to change edit mode - I've searched everywhere!

Comment: @Andrey, sorry no.  I would suggest following tutorials on the Oracle site and see if there is support forums available.  You may have pointed to read-only files.